# Definición de dll en archivos JNLP

Tags: java

Buenas, alguien sabe como introducir un ambiente de ejecución dentro de un archivo jnlp? o bien, en tags de resources como definir dll?.

Lo que pasa es que estoy desarrollando un sistema java que se conecta a un sistema cobol para solicitar datos. Localmente funciona sin problemas pero al momento de ejecutarlo vía Java Web Start, se tranca la aplicación cuando hace el llamado a un programa en visual cobol, el cual se comunica con el cobol nativo.

Todo indica que no reconoce al cobol, por lo que asumo que lo que faltaría es definir las librerías que se utilizan en el ambiente de desarrollo.

Desde ya muchas gracias.